# Running a Zend_Application from the command line?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-application

Is there a *blessed* way to run a Zend_Application from the command line?  That is, I want to run a shell script that invokes a Zend_Application, loads its configuration, and then calls a specific controller action OR run an arbitrary command line script with access to the applications configurations, models, etc.

I can think of a few ways to hack this together, but it seems like the kind of thing where there may be an official (but poorly documented) way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[here's](http://webfractor.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/using-zend-framework-from-the-command-line/) one way: http://webfractor.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/using-zend-framework-from-the-command-line/

if there is actually a web server in the mix, you could also of course trigger w/wget or lynx... wget --quiet http://server/app/doTheThing